# How to get the max array size from nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, lodash, data-manipulation

I've got the following example object. There could be any depth of of data, not just the example of 3.

```
{
  'name': 'Clifford Shanks',
  'born': 1862,
  'died': 1906,
  'location': 'Petersburg, VA',
  'children': [
    {
      'name': 'Elizabeth Shanks',
      'born': 1795,
      'died': 1871,
      'location': 'Ireland/Petersburg, VA'
    }
  ],
  'parents': [
    {
      'name': 'James Shanks',
      'born': 1831,
      'died': 1884,
      'location': 'Petersburg, VA',
      'parents': [
        {
          'name': 'Robert Shanks',
          'born': 1781,
          'died': 1871,
          'location': 'Ireland/Petersburg, VA'
        },
        {
          'name': 'Elizabeth Shanks',
          'born': 1795,
          'died': 1871,
          'location': 'Ireland/Petersburg, VA'
        },
        {
          'name': 'Elizabeth Shanks',
          'born': 1795,
          'died': 1871,
          'location': 'Ireland/Petersburg, VA'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'name': 'Ann Emily Brown',
      'born': 1826,
      'died': 1866,
      'location': 'Brunswick/Petersburg, VA',
      'parents': [
        {
          'name': 'Henry Brown',
          'born': 1792,
          'died': 1845,
          'location': 'Montgomery, NC'
        },
        {
          'name': 'Sarah Houchins',
          'born': 1793,
          'died': 1882,
          'location': 'Montgomery, NC'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want something to give me the answer `3` as one of the `parents` arrays has a length of 3. I though I would use lodash to pluck out all the arrays and the I'd be able to figure things out form there but when I `_.pluck(data, 'parents')` I get

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

which is odd more than anything because there are only 3 `parents` arrays but I get 6 undefineds back.

Any idea how to get the maximum `parents` array size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an unspecified depth of data, recursion is a good way to traverse the data. I don't think lodash's `pluck` will do a deep dive into a tree-like structure like your example.

```
var maxParents = 0;
var findMaxParents = function(data) {

  // if there are grandparents, let's see how many there are
  if(data.parents && data.parents.length > 0) {
    data.parents.forEach(function(parent){
      findMaxParents(parent);
    });
  }

  if(data.parents && data.parents.length > maxParents) {
    maxParents = data.parents.length;
  }
  return maxParents;
}
```

And here's a JSFiddle with some console.logging as well: http://jsfiddle.net/uerwzm0L/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your entire object above is assigned to var obj:

```
var size = 0;

obj.parents.forEach(function(parent) {
    if(parent.parents && parent.parents.length > size)
        size = parent.parents.length
})

// If you need to include the 'parent' parents array size, 
// add the following check
if(obj.parents.length > size)
     size = obj.parents.length;
// end check

return size;
```